# Выборка записей с последним изменением статуса

Tags: mysql

В бд хранится история изменений статусов заявки, необходимо чтобы выводились на страницу только записи с последним изменением статуса.

```
select requests.fio, requests.stud_group, statuses.name, requests.type_name, request_statuses.comment 
from requests 
inner join request_statuses on requests.id=request_statuses.id_request 
inner join statuses on statuses.id=request_statuses.id_status;
```

То что выделено на скрине желтым, выводить не надо, потому что их статус был изменен, необходимо вывести то что в красных рамках.

[image: Выделенное желтым не надо]

[image: БД]

Comment: непонятно. Что значит: "записи с последним изменением статуса."?? Это не отличие по `new` и по `created at`

Comment: каждый раз когда мы хотим изменить статус заявки, мы вводим новую запись, чтобы сохранять историю. Необходимо чтобы выводилась заявка по последней дате, то есть добавив запись в таблицу request_statuses с изначальным статусом new, после изменив(то есть добавив новую запись в request_statuses) её статус на wait, нам нужно вывести именно запись со статусом wait из таблицы request_statuses, не выводя запись со статусом new

Comment: 1) и как сочетается "не выводя запись со статусом new" и ранее написанное "необходимо вывести то что в красных рамках", где у первой же записи в красной рамке статус "new"? 2) В чем вообще тут сложность? По описанию задача элементарная (после ясной формулировки условий)

Comment: У нас есть запись "Иванов"  со статусом "new". Мы изменяем его статус например на wait. Теперь у нас в бд две записи. "Иванов" "new"  и "Иванов" "wait". Нужно, чтобы выводилась последняя добавленная запись, т.е. "Иванов" "wait".  Потом мы заявку выполнили и поставили статус  "Иванов " "success". Значит теперь он нам должен вывести только эту последнюю добавленную запись   "Иванов " "success".

Comment: ясно, но мне уходить пора. Возможно, вечером тогда.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT LAST_VALUE(column)`. Или стандартная нумерация в CTE

Comment: ну, собственно, уже ответили выше:-)